# Does putting hooks into a function component cause it to have an instance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

In [the documentation about refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) we are told:

> You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they
> don’t have instances.

This seems to mean that we can't get a `ref` to most modern components, because we're all [following the advice to build them as function components with hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both).

Or ... is it the case that function components with hooks do in fact have an instance, and are able to be referred to with a `ref`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear:

- You can *use* refs in function components just fine (usually via `useRef`).
- You can't use a ref directly on a function component if that function component doesn't [forward](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) the ref to one of its children.

So if you try to use `<X ref={ref} />` and `X` is a function component that doesn't forward refs, you'll get an error:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const X = (props) => {
    return <div>ExampleFunction</div>;
};

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>
            <X ref={this.ref}/>
        </div>;
    }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That's because the "instance" of a function component is an implementation detail of React itself (basically an array of hook data storage slots), not something React gives you access to.

But the function component can *forward* the ref to one of its children. Here's an example of the distinction between a ref on a class component and a ref on a function component that forwards it:

```js
const { useState } = React;

class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>ExampleClass</div>;
    }
}

const ExampleFunction = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>ExampleFunction</div>;
});

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref1 = React.createRef();
        this.ref2 = React.createRef();
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("ref1 is an instance of ExampleClass", this.ref1.current instanceof ExampleClass); // true
        console.log("ref2 is an instance of HTMLElement:", this.ref2.current instanceof HTMLElement); // true
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>
            <ExampleClass ref={this.ref1}/>
            <ExampleFunction ref={this.ref2}/>
        </div>;
    }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

As you can see, with the `class` component you actually get a reference to the instance of the class. With the function component, you get a reference to the child it forwarded the ref to.

> Does putting hooks into a function component cause it to have an instance?

Honestly I couldn't tell you whether function components have "instances" (in a loose sense) if you don't use hooks in them or not; I suspect they do, though, for various pieces of React internal information (if you want to dig through the source, you can find out for sure). But unlike a `class` component, you can't directly access that internal "instance."

Comment: "So if you try to use <X ref={ref} /> and X is a function component that doesn't forward refs, you'll get an error"  that's the exact case I was concerned with.    The issue I am struggling with (now that this is clear) is:  How do I know if any given component <X/> that I am using in my own one is in fact functional or not, and whether it won't tomorrow be refactored to be functional?

Comment: @GreenAsJade - You don't, but normally you use a ref on a component for a specific reason supported by that component, so the component's documentation will tell you what you can and can't do with it with a ref, and presumably won't break that between one dot release and the next (major releases are a different matter).

Comment: @GreenAsJade - (Side note: it's "function component," not "functional component." A function component using hooks usually isn't [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). :-) )

Comment: Makes sense. My case, then, is a bit corner: I want to create a component that _needs_ a ref from a companion/parent ... the component it will "work with" (annotate).   But ... it seems I can't rely on being able to get a ref for any arbitrary React component... that's a puzzle!

Comment: (Side note: I know, dagnabit, I just can't type those letters without ending in `al` auto-type!)

Comment: @GreenAsJade - (Side note: **LOL!!** :-) )

Comment: @GreenAsJade - What does the "annotation" involve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245849/discussion-between-greenasjade-and-t-j-crowder).